# fseek does not work with empty file

Tags: c, fseek

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;

    if(argc != 2){
        perror("Please specify a file");
        return 1;
    }

    if((fp=fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == 0){
        perror("File not found!");
        return 2;
    }

    int a = fseek(fp, 1000, SEEK_CUR);

    if(a<0){
        printf("fail\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

When I call this with an empty binary file, no error occurs, eve though I would expect fseek() to return with -1. Does anyone know why is this not happening?

Comment: Yes, thats the case. Thanks!

Comment: This is by design. If you invoke an `fwrite(string, 1, strlen(string), fp)` call after the `fseek` call in your program, the file will get padded with 1000 null chars before the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)

> POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file. If an output is
>   performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero
>   bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a sparse file.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. `fseek` do not fail when you seek past end-of-file.